# WSGI problem on Eleastic Beanstalk with Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Some days ago I have deployed a Django on AWS elastic beanstalk(EB) and it worked fine. Today, after a new deploy, where I did minor changes in view.py, the Django APP on EB has a very big problem and it becomes not accessible anymore. Looking at the log file in AWS EB I read this errors:

```
 Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py
 End of script output before headers: wsgi.py, referer ...
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve this issues?

I would like to thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Two potential solutions (depending on your specific situation)

This is a similar question in addressing this specific question
[End of script output before headers: wsgi.py deploying python django to AWS EB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009092/end-of-script-output-before-headers-wsgi-py-deploying-python-django-to-aws-eb)

Add this WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} to your wsgi configuration. It directs your wsgi app- your django app, to "run within the very first Python sub interpreter created when Python is initialised" (from https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api)

The other solution is related to increaseing memory of the instance you are using.